# Assigning a procedure to dynamically created object

Tags: delphi, variable-assignment, lazarus, eventhandler, address-operator

I want to dynamically create `TImage` controls and then drag and drop them. But if I want to assign the procedure used for the dragging to an event of this Image, it gives me:

> Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "ClickEvent"

This is my code for the dragging:

```
procedure ClickEvent(Sender:TObject; Button:TMouseButton; Shift:TShiftstate; X,Y:Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then TControl(Sender).BeginDrag(False);
end;
```

And here I create the Image and add the properties:

```
procedure SpawnCard(Ort:TWinControl; sKarte:TKarteClass; Liste: Array of TKarte; BilderListe:Array of TCustomImage);
var
  Bild:TImage;
begin
  Liste[High(Liste)]:=sKarte.Create();

  Bild:=TImage.Create(Combat);
  with Bild do
  begin
    OnMouseDown:=ClickEvent;
    Parent:=Ort;
    Top:=1;
    Left:=200*length(BilderListe);
    width:=200;
    height:=300;
    Proportional:=True;
    Stretch:=True;
    Picture.LoadFromFile(Liste[High(Liste)].PicPath);
  end;

  BilderListe[High(BilderListe)]:=Bild;

end;
```

I don't want to call `ClickEvent`, I just want to assign it to the event.

Comment: Try `OnMouseDown := @ClickEvent`, but your procedure needs to be a class method, unless you use a `TMethod` hack to use a standalone procedure with a manual explicit `Self` pointer

Comment: Also parameters `Liste` and `BilderListe` only exist locally - assignments to them don't remain when the procedure ends and are, as of now, pointless. Consider prefixing both parameters with `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TImage.OnMouseDown` (inherited from its `TControl` parent class) is a `TMouseEvent` property.

```
  TMouseEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
    Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer) of object;
```

As you can see, it's declared as "of object", which means it expects a method pointer (See the [Method Pointers section](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Procedural_Types_(Delphi))).

---

**Example 1:**

Declare the `ClickEvent` on the form (or any other object):

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
  public
    procedure ClickEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.ClickEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then TControl(Sender).BeginDrag(False);
end;
```

Then you can assign it as follows:

```
  Image1.OnMouseDown := Form1.ClickEvent;
```

---

**Example 2:**

Declare the `ClickEvent` as a [class method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_Methods):

```
  TMyEventHandlers = class
    class procedure ClickEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  end;

...

class procedure TMyEventHandlers.ClickEvent(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then TControl(Sender).BeginDrag(False);
end;
```

Then you can assign it as follows:

```
Image1.OnMouseDown := TMyEventHandlers.ClickEvent;
```

Comment: No, it must be at least `Image1.OnMouseDown := Form1.ClickEvent;` because where it is assigned there is no context of `Form1`.

Comment: Updated. Anyhow, I think the second example would fit better for his scenario

Comment: For some reason, it only works with `Image1.OnMouseDown := @TMyEventHandlers.ClickEvent;` when I try it.

Comment: That's probably related to the IDE's version. I've tested using Delphi XE7

Comment: I am using Lazarus. It probably doesn't work there then.

Comment: @Boi That's because you don't use [`-MDelphi` or `-MTP` on your Free Pascal Compiler](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse17.html) - with those the `@` operator is not needed anymore, as per the documentation.