# Making a function return a procedure

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Normally, a function returns a normal data type, like a string, eg:

```
Function getInitials(sName,sSurname:string) :string
Begin
  Result := sName [1]+sSurname [1]
End
```

And is called like this:

```
var s: string;

s := getInitials (John, Wick);
// s will have the value 'JW'
```

As you can see, the `Result` is assigned a value using `:=`.

What if we need to allow the end user to create a *CUSTOM* `OnClick` event for a dynamic button?

```
Var
  BtnNEW: TButton;

Procedure MakeButtonInRuntime;
Const 
  sLine = 'formColor=Red'
Begin
  BtnNEW := TButton.Create(frmHome);
  With btnNew DO
  Begin
    Name := btnRed;
    OnClick := MakeOnClick(sLine);
  End
End

Function MakeOnClick(doThis: string) : procedure;
Begin
  Result := (frmHome.color := clRed);
End;
```

So, the plan is that once the program runs, a brand new `TButton` is made.
The button then gets a custom `OnClick` (from a function) based from `sLine`. In this case, it will give the button the ability to change the form's colors once clicked.

The problem is that the compiler doesn't work with this code as the syntax is not getting a normal data type and instead a procedure.

Comment: Similar questions with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265513/setting-the-onclick-procedure-of-a-delphi-button-at-runtime
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679624/assigning-a-procedure-to-dynamically-created-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning a procedure to dynamically created object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679624/assigning-a-procedure-to-dynamically-created-object)

Comment: With ref to this: *...the end user to create a CUSTOM onclick event for a dynamic button*, the question is what freedom you want to give the end user? Write whatever code he likes, or select from a number of given and written by you methods?

Comment: All your 3 code examples aren't valid: semicolons and String literal delimiters are missing (i.e. `John` versus `'John'`).